# Ignoring python warnings

Tags: python

I want to ignore all the `UserWarning` in my dev environment so that they are not printed into my error log file.

I've read the documentation of `warnings` module, and tried something like:

```
import warnings
import the_module_that_warns

warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)
```

But `UserWarning` still get printed, why's that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If the modules warns on it import, the way you do it is too late.

Instead, do

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)

import the_module_that_warns
```

in order to tell the `warnings` module what to ignore before the warning comes.

Comment: Just figured it out ;) Thanks all the same.

Comment: what do you mean by the_module_that_warns

Comment: @Albert The same as in the question: a module which issues a warning during its import process.