# Python supress warnings while creating a empty pcap file with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, suppress-warnings

I want to create an empty `pcap` file. I'm using `wrpcap` module of 'Scapy'. But `wrpcap` takes exactly `2 arguments`: one is the `file name` and other is the `packet list` like:

```
wrpcap("my.pcap",my_pkt_list)
```

Since I want to make it, empty and I don't have a packet list, I'm writing an empty string to the `pcap` file. Which is creating the file but also giving a warning as well as errors since a string doesn't match to a packet type.

```
WARNING: PcapWriter: unknown LL type for str. Using type 1 (Ethernet)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    wrpcap("pcap/FU.pcap","")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/utils.py", line 466, in wrpcap
    PcapWriter(filename, *args, **kargs).write(pkt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/utils.py", line 646, in write
    self._write_packet(pkt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/utils.py", line 688, in _write_packet
    sec = int(packet.time)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'time'
```

For now, I'm able to suppress the errors with `try and except` but unable to suppress the warning.

**Code**

```
from scapy.all import *
try:
    wrpcap("my.pcap","")
except:
    pass
```

and the warning is still there:

```
WARNING: PcapWriter: unknown LL type for str. Using type 1 (Ethernet)
```

How to suppress it from inside the python code?

Comment: Did `python -W ignore file.py`, or any other solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) not work?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175388/ignoring-python-warnings . This should do the trick:

`import warnings`
`warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)`

Comment: @RomanK Thanks for the reference. I tried that but it's not working. do we need to write `UserWarning` or anything else at that place?

Comment: @RatDon - Maybe you can use Warning instead of UserWarning? The former is the parent class for all warning types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid that warning by using `PcapWriter` method of scapy.

```
from scapy.all import *
try:
    writer=PcapWriter("my.pcap")
except:
    pass
```

This creates your empty pcap file. When you want to write some packets to it, just use the following code:

```
writer.write(<Your_packets>)
writer.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a nice method I never looked. May be I need to change my title of the question. :P

Answer (score 3):

Python has a built in method in the standard library for supressing warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", Warning)
```

You can read more about the warnings library [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html).

**EDIT**

It doesn't look like `scapy` uses the `warnings` library to generate this. Instead it [logs them to a logger](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/src/5b6a45cb1bb78ae0764dc16ad31f758558c53b9f/scapy/error.py?at=default#cl-52) called `scapy.runtime` with a level of `warning`. There's obviously some default logging config to echo that to `stdout`. You could add your own logging handler for `scapy.runtime` to supress them.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress this warning by disabling warning logging before the call `wrpcap`:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The text "WARNING: ..." is not part of the exception and will thus not be surpressed by your try clause.

An idea I got was to redirect stdout during the call

```
from scapy.all import *
try:
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = None
    wrpcap("my.pcap","")
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
except:
    pass
```

that should surpress any and all output during the call

Comment: The idea is good. But will not suppress any other outputs of the program?

Comment: It will disable all output to stdout during the call to wrpcap , so if you have several processes their output will have their output be surpressed aswell.